# Utility or Source Code for UDP File Transfer Over Unreliable Unidirectional Network?

Tags: networking

I need to transfer data between two machines over an unreliable one-way network. To meet my reliablity requirements, I intend to use forward error correction (FEC). Is there a library, source code or utility that implements a point-to-point UDP connection with FEC?

udpcast comes close to what I want; it implements FEC and has an option for a point-to-point UDP connection. Unfortunately, it coordinates the client and server through a multicast channel, and I cannot use multicast. (And I do not see any way to avoid that in udpcast.)

Any pointers or help will be appreciated!

Comment: A library for what programming language? A utility for what platform? Any license considerations, price limits?

Comment: I'm generally agnostic -- I could manage most languages and either Windows or Linux.  I don't think there are any COTS/commercial tools that would do, but I'd certainly like to hear about them if so.